# Java ternary operator: should check for condition or !condition?

Tags: java, ternary-operator, conventions

this might sound as a silly question, but is there a convention when assigning values using a ternary operation when it comes to **checking for not null (not condition) or checking for null (condition)**?

For example, which of the below would make more sense from this point of view?

```
List<A> aList = something != null ? something : new ArrayList<>();

List<A> aList = something == null ? new ArrayList<>() : something;
```

Both do the job, I'm curious though if there's an underlying difference between them.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is any performance difference between the two.  They should both boil down to very similarly structured if-else statements.

Comment: Just a matter of taste, closing as opinion based.

Comment: @Mircea Man, Both are same, you can create a number of combinations which can perform the same operation.

Comment: No functional difference, and I don't know of any convention. I usually prefer the `==` variant, as I like to keep compound lines as simple as possible, and "not equals" is one step more complicated than "equals"... but the flip side is that using `!=` lets you put the default value second, which fits my intuition better. But basically, you do you.

Comment: Don't know of any convention except that as a team, you can agree on any convention that you deem necessary.

Comment: No convention or best practice here. It basically boils down to what you consider to be more readable.

Comment: (Btw, this is to me an interesting case of a question that should _not_ be closed as primarily opinion-based. The question is asking whether there's any difference, or convention. There's objectively no difference, and I would guess a very broad consensus that there's no convention. Thus, the answer is fairly objectively "no, there's no difference or convention.")

Comment: Intro to have the more complex/longer expression at the end. If both are nearly the same I look for the more natural condition. In your case there is no obvious winner. I would lean towards the first if something usually is not null and the default is only a fallback.

Answer (score 3):

There is no practical difference between the two, and, as far as I aware of, no convention for it either. I prefer the "== null" though, as negations use to be more mind-boggling to read.

Answer (score 3):

There is no convention when it comes to ternary operators, nor any difference in performance.

Answer (score 3):

As already said. There is no difference between the two options and it is basically a matter of readability or taste.

However, in the special case of checking for `null` you might want to take a look at Java8's `Optional`. This is pretty nice to use and improves readability a lot, if used correctly.

```
Optional<List<A>> optList = Optional.ofNullable(something);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no performance differences between the two.

For readability I will prefer the first one because it is more intuitive.

- First one says : assign the value of `something` to `aList` if `something` is not `null`, otherwise an `empty list`
- Second one says: check if `something` is null. If it is `null`, assign an `empty list` to `aList` , other wise `something`